# internal links from nested DIV tags not working

Tags: html

Having an issue with the following HTML:

iDreamMobile
    
    
    
    //

```
// Perform setup after the document loads:
$(function() {

    // Add a class to caption elements:
    $('.caption').addClass('darkBlue');

    // Generate tabs:
    $('#content').tabs();

    // Add a click event to the message button:
    $('#messageButton').click(showHideMessage);

    // Initially hide the message:
    $('#message').hide();


});

// This function is called when the button is clicked.
function showHideMessage(e) {
    $('#message').toggle('slow');
}


// ]]>
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery.tabs.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />

<style type="text/css">
    #messageButton {
    font-size: small;
    color: #DDDDDD;
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .darkBlue {
    color: #27537a;
    }

    div#home {
    color: #a3a3a3;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#home a {
    color: #a3a3a3;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    div#idb a {
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 64px;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div id="content">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home"><span style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#DD44DD;">Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#a"><span style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#3333BB;">iDB</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#b"><span style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#33DD99;">iDT</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#c"><span style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#B0FF5E;">iDV</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#d"><span style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color:#FFCC66;">iDS</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="home" align="center" style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="link_to_a" style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="#a"><img src="assets/a_btn_57.png" /><br />Page A</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="link_to_b" style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="#b"><img src="assets/b_btn_57.png" /><br />Page B</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div id="link_to_c" style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="#c"><img src="assets/c_btn_57.png" /><br />Page C</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="link_to_d" style="font-family:helvetica; font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; color: #a3a3a3; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="#d"><img src="assets/d_btn_57.png" /><br />Page D</a>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
    <div id="a" align="center">
        <img src="assets/slide_image.png"><br />
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/add_image_48.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/add_music_48.png" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/add_note_48.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="b" align="center">
        <table style="font-family:helvetica; font-size:12px;" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5px">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
        <td>Task</td>
        <td>Due Date</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>placeholder</td>
        <td>placeholder</td>
        <td>placeholder</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="c" align="center">
    <iframe src="flash_video.swf" frameborder="0" width="320px" height="240px"> </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        <div id="ds_postTo" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:18px;">Share your content on:</div>
```

various social networking links

Or log into our own social network.

Menu
            This is the options menu.

The links in the top list work flawlessly for getting to the contents of DIVs a thru d, but the links inside of the "link_to_a" thru "link_to_d" are not working...

I'm probably doing something dumb here - any pointers?

Comment: can you include complete html ? anchors where links should point?  Your code looks ok, except that you miss  </div> at the end of your code snippet.

Comment: What would make the links "work?"

Comment: Why are the inner links linking to the same place they are located?

Comment: OK - here is the complete HTML, hopefully it makes more sense...

Comment: edited original post to include complete html

Comment: @Detect - for the links to 'work', I want the user to see the contents of div ID 'a' rather than 'home' when they click the button. It works when they click the tab at the top, but not the button within the 'home' div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that some  tags are not closed.

The W3C validator will help you to debug it:  http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Also these links are supposed to **scroll** your page to certain divs (right?). So you will see the effect only if you reduce your browser window.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `anchors` to go from place to place in webpage. You need to reference the `id` of the location you want.

Check out the fiddle, I have added the proper targets below and both anchors work fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/YXxwz/

Comment: that's not what he is trying to do. Looks like he tries to link to some anchors that he didn't include.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't working, and once I used that method the links in the <ul> at the top stopped working as well...

Comment: Dmitriy - I have the DIVs a through d further down the page - just didn't want to make the post too long.

Comment: @kolys, do those `DIV`s have `id`s?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the links that don't work to use JavaScript if they aren't being binded correctly.

`$('#content').tabs('select', index)`